Simulating the population of Canada
I have this data frame in R about quarterly population.
library(readr)

url <- url <- "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1710000901&latestN=0&startDate=19800101&endDate=20240701&csvLocale=en&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C14%2C15%5D%5D&checkedLevels="

data <- read_csv(url)
data <- data[data$GEO == "Canada", ]
data$date_column <- as.Date(paste(data$REF_DATE, "-01", sep = ""), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
final_df <- data %>%
  select(date_column, VALUE) %>%
  arrange(date_column)

From here, I am trying to interpolate the missing values via simulation and the plot the average results:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

generate_monthly_data <- function(start_date, end_date, start_value, end_value, sd_factor = 0.01) {
  months_seq <- seq(start_date %m+% months(1), end_date %m-% months(1), by = "month")
  n_months <- length(months_seq)

  if (n_months > 0) {
    values <- seq(start_value, end_value, length.out = n_months + 2)[-c(1, n_months + 2)]
    sd <- sd_factor * mean(c(start_value, end_value))
    values <- values + rnorm(n_months, mean = 0, sd = sd)
    data.frame(date_column = months_seq, VALUE = round(values))
  } else {
    data.frame(date_column = as.Date(character()), VALUE = numeric())
  }
}

simulate_monthly_data <- function(df) {
  result <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
    start_date <- df$date_column[i]
    end_date <- df$date_column[i + 1]
    start_value <- df$VALUE[i]
    end_value <- df$VALUE[i + 1]

    result <- rbind(result, df[i, ])

    monthly_data <- generate_monthly_data(start_date, end_date, start_value, end_value)
    result <- rbind(result, monthly_data)
  }

  result <- rbind(result, df[nrow(df), ])

  result
}

set.seed(123)
simulations <- list()
for (i in 1:50) {
  simulations[[i]] <- simulate_monthly_data(final_df)
  simulations[[i]]$simulation <- i
}

all_simulations <- do.call(rbind, simulations)

mean_simulations <- all_simulations %>%
  group_by(date_column) %>%
  summarise(mean_VALUE = mean(VALUE))

legend_data <- data.frame(
  x = as.Date(c("1980-01-01", "1980-01-01")),
  y = c(max(all_simulations$VALUE), max(all_simulations$VALUE)),
  label = c("Simulation", "Original Data")
)

common_theme <- theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(
    data = all_simulations, aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE, group = simulation),
    alpha = 0.1, color = "blue"
  ) +
  geom_point(data = final_df, aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE), color = "red", size = 2) +
  geom_point(data = legend_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = label), size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Simulation" = "blue", "Original Data" = "red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = label_number(suffix = " M", scale = 1e-6),
    breaks = seq(0, max(all_simulations$VALUE), by = 5000000)
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(
    title = "50 Simulations of Monthly Data",
    subtitle = "Red points show original quarterly data",
    x = "Date",
    y = "Value (Millions)",
    color = "Data Type"
  ) +
  common_theme

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = mean_simulations, aes(x = date_column, y = mean_VALUE), color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = label_number(suffix = " M", scale = 1e-6),
    breaks = seq(0, max(mean_simulations$mean_VALUE), by = 5000000)
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(
    title = "Mean of 50 Simulations",
    x = "Date",
    y = "Value (Millions)"
  ) +
  common_theme +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

combined_plot <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)

combined_plot

Everything looks good, but I am noticing that the in the top left of the first plot, this weird point keeps appearing:
Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix this?

Stefan's answer worked!
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

# Load and prepare data
url <- "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/dtl!downloadDbLoadingData-nonTraduit.action?pid=1710000901&latestN=0&startDate=19800101&endDate=20240701&csvLocale=en&selectedMembers=%5B%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C14%2C15%5D%5D&checkedLevels="

data <- read_csv(url)
data <- data[data$GEO == "Canada", ]
data$date_column <- as.Date(paste(data$REF_DATE, "-01", sep = ""), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
final_df <- data %>%
  select(date_column, VALUE) %>%
  arrange(date_column)

# Functions for data simulation
generate_monthly_data <- function(start_date, end_date, start_value, end_value, sd_factor = 0.01) {
  months_seq <- seq(start_date %m+% months(1), end_date %m-% months(1), by = "month")
  n_months <- length(months_seq)

  if (n_months > 0) {
    values <- seq(start_value, end_value, length.out = n_months + 2)[-c(1, n_months + 2)]
    sd <- sd_factor * mean(c(start_value, end_value))
    values <- values + rnorm(n_months, mean = 0, sd = sd)
    data.frame(date_column = months_seq, VALUE = round(values))
  } else {
    data.frame(date_column = as.Date(character()), VALUE = numeric())
  }
}

simulate_monthly_data <- function(df) {
  result <- data.frame()

  for (i in 1:(nrow(df) - 1)) {
    start_date <- df$date_column[i]
    end_date <- df$date_column[i + 1]
    start_value <- df$VALUE[i]
    end_value <- df$VALUE[i + 1]

    result <- rbind(result, df[i, ])

    monthly_data <- generate_monthly_data(start_date, end_date, start_value, end_value)
    result <- rbind(result, monthly_data)
  }

  result <- rbind(result, df[nrow(df), ])

  result
}

# Run simulations
set.seed(123)
simulations <- list()
for (i in 1:50) {
  simulations[[i]] <- simulate_monthly_data(final_df)
  simulations[[i]]$simulation <- i
}

all_simulations <- do.call(rbind, simulations)

mean_simulations <- all_simulations %>%
  group_by(date_column) %>%
  summarise(mean_VALUE = mean(VALUE))

# Plotting
common_theme <- theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(
    data = all_simulations, 
    aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE, group = simulation, color = "Simulation"),
    alpha = 0.1
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = final_df, 
    aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE, color = "Original Data"), 
    size = 2
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("Simulation" = "blue", "Original Data" = "red"),
    name = "Data Type"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = label_number(suffix = " M", scale = 1e-6),
    breaks = seq(0, max(all_simulations$VALUE), by = 5000000)
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(
    title = "50 Simulations of Monthly Data",
    subtitle = "Red points show original quarterly data",
    x = "Date",
    y = "Value (Millions)"
  ) +
  common_theme

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = mean_simulations, aes(x = date_column, y = mean_VALUE), color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = label_number(suffix = " M", scale = 1e-6),
    breaks = seq(0, max(mean_simulations$mean_VALUE), by = 5000000)
  ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  labs(
    title = "Mean of 50 Simulations",
    x = "Date",
    y = "Value (Millions)"
  ) +
  common_theme +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

combined_plot <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)

combined_plot

Welcome to SO! You add these points via the code line geom_point(data = legend_data, aes(x = x, y = y, color = label), size = 3) which you use to create a legend. Drop this line and instead use e.g. geom_line(data = all_simulations, aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE, group = simulation, color = "Simulation"), alpha = 0.1) and geom_point(data = final_df, aes(x = date_column, y = VALUE, color = "Original Data"), size = 2) to add your legend.

thank you so much!
